# How to config cscope in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 as my os, I am using emacs in Gnome.

I have installed emacs and cscope successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs

sudo apt-get install cscope
```

then run command in the directory of the source code folder in my terminal, and the index files have been produced.

```
cscope-indexer
```

and add the following stuf in .emacs in home/username folder

```
(require 'xcscope)
```

However, there isn't a short-cut ,'CSCOPE', in the emacs ui and when I use ctrl_c + s to use cscope, emacs said it's undefined.

What should i do now to make cscope run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xcscope) of xcscope seems to provide a lot of information on the default keybindings and how to configure it properly.

However, you seem to have a bit too many `)` in your require statement, did you copy it right? it should just be:

```
(require 'xcscope)
```

and that's it, outside of any other parenthesis.